# When does the blogspot "day" begin?

Tags: blogger

When blogspot is calculating "today's" statistics, what time (UTC) does the day start?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The day starts at midnight UTC according to [this](http://blogging.nitecruzr.net/2010/11/ongoing-problems-with-stats.html) post.

> ... it appears that it's setup to reset counts for all blogs,
>   simultaneously, at midnight UTC (aka "GMT").